# What do group() and contents[] mean?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'am learning about the modules of `re` and `BeautifulSoup`. I have a doubt in few lines of the next code. I don't know the use of `group()` and what's inside of brackets in `contents[]`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

url = 'http://www.ebay.es/itm/LOTE-5-BOTES-CERVEZAARGUS-SET-5-BEER-CANSLOT-5-CANETTES-BIRES-LATTINE-BIRRA-/321162173293'  #raw_input('URL: ')   
code = urllib2.urlopen(url).read();
soup = BeautifulSoup(code)
tag = soup.find('span', id='v4-27').contents[0]

price_string = re.search('(\d+,\d+)', tag).group(1)
precio_final = float(price_string.replace(',' , '.'))

print precio_final
```

Comment: You can get the points easily from their docs. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [re](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) returns a list of items from a tag. For example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> soup = BS('<span class="foo"> bar baz <a href="http://foo.com">link</a></span>')
>>> print soup.find('span').contents
[u' bar baz ', <a href="http://foo.com">link</a>]
```

`[0]` is used to access the first element of the list `.contents` returns. In the example above, it will return `bar baz`

[`.group(1)`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) returns the second (indexing starts at 0, remember) matched value from a regular expression. Looking at your regular expression, it returns the second digit from something that looks like `n1,n2`.